# C#: "Using" Statements with HttpWebRequests/HttpWebResponses

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, using, httpwebresponse, using-statement

Jon Skeet [made a comment (via Twitter)](http://twitter.com/jonskeet/statuses/6625278613) on my [SOApiDotNet](http://soapidotnet.googlecode.com) code (a .NET library for the pre-alpha Stack Overflow API):

> @maximz2005 One thing I've noticed
> just from browsing the source quickly:
> you don't disposed (sic) of WebResponses.
> "using" statements FTW.

He indicates that I need to wrap these Web sessions in "using" statements. However, I have a question about this: should I **wrap the whole thing, starting with the HttpWebRequest**, **or should I create the WebRequest outside of the "using" statement and then wrap the Response inside**? I have a feeling that the difference is that, in the former, both objects would be disposed of - is this correct?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`HttpWebRequest` itself is not disposable unlike `HttpWebResponse`. You should wrap disposable resources with using to allow early and determined cleanup. Correctly implemented `IDisposable` pattern allows multiple calls to `Dispose` without any issues so even the outer using statement wraps resource that during its own dispose disposes inner using statement resource it is still ok.

**Code example**

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("example.com"); 
using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse()) 
{ 
    // Code here 
}
```

Comment: So should I declare ..Request outside, or what?

Comment: Yes, that means you'd do a var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://example.com");
using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse()) {
// Code here
}

Comment: @Dzmitry, @Benjamin. I added Benjamin's code example to your answer.

Answer (score 6):

Everything wrapped in a using () {} block (that is, inside of the first brackets) is disposed when you leave the scope.

I haven't used your library so far (seems nice though), but I'd argue that you should explicitly dispose every IDisposable you create (= are responsible for) and don't return to a caller.

A sidenote, since I've seen a lot of people struggling with multiple things to dispose: Instead of

```
using (var foo = SomeIDisposable) {
  using (var bar = SomeOtherIDisposable) {
  }
}
```

which needs a lot of vertical space you can write

```
using (var foo = SomeIDisposable)
using (var bar = SomeOtherIDisposable) {
}
```

Comment: Your second paragraph (which is correct, I believe) contradicts the first. If everything inside the using-block is disposed, you wouldn't need the inner using statement.

Comment: See my updated post: Everything inside of using (...) is disposed when you leave the following block (this part: { ... })

Answer (score 1):

In order to prevent memory leaks you should call Dispose on every object that implements IDisposable. You can ensure that the Dispose method in called by using the using keyword (no pun intended) as it is just a syntactic sugar for try-finally block.